# Why is msg.value an uint and not an int in Solidity?

Tags: solidity

This value cannot be negative, can it? I am annoyed because I cannot cast this to an int or do not know how to.

Answer (score 2):

`msg.value` can not be negative.

you can simply cast `msg.value` to `int` like this

```
 int castedValue = (int) (msg.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

because msg.value refers to the amount of wei(eth in gas smallest unit) you're sending to the recipient.

Do you have negative amounts on your account ? not sure about that.
+
you can cast it to an int with traditional manual typecasting.

Comment: So it's possible to send a negative amount?

Comment: you can cast the original value to an int, but the type of msg.value is unsigned int.
So no you can't

Comment: an unsigned int is 256 bit, from 0 to (2 power of 256 )-1